# Polynomial with complex coefficients proof problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients such that $P(n) = 0$ for all integer $n$. Prove that $P(z) = 0$ for all $z \in C$.

Comment: Any nonconstant polynomial must have at most finitely many zeroes.  Since there are countably infinite integers and P vanishes at all of them, P must be a constant polynomial; clearly, it must be the constant-zero polynomial.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass hi, so P=0? Is that what u mean, but I don't get it why in the question it says it's with complex coefficient

Comment: It doesn't matter if a polynomial has complex or real coefficients. The idea is that it can only have a finite number of roots. Thus, this is a useful fact that you can learn about polynomials: if a polynomial has infinitely many roots then it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @BeniBogosel wait, if a polynomial has "infinitely" or "finitely" many roots?

Comment: The only case where a polynomial has infinitely many roots is where the polynomial is equal to zero everywhere. Then every number is a root. If a polynomial is not constant zero then it has finitely many roots.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ differents roots : indeed, by euclidian division you get :
$$\alpha\text{ is a root of }P\iff(X-\alpha)\mid P$$
 Here you can see that the degree $d$ of your polynomial can't be in $\mathbb{N}$ because $1,2,3,...,d-1,d,d+1$ will be $d+1>d$ different roots : so the only choice for your polynomial is to be the zero polynomial.

Comment: To show that polynomial has at most $d$ roots doesn't require FTA. If $f$ has degree $d$ and root $a$, then $f(x)/(x-a)$ has degree $d-1$. Use induction.

Comment: Sorry I still can't see why the only choice for my polynomial is the zero polynomial

Comment: @user281392 : Yes it is indeed too strong, I will edit that. Thank you !

Comment: Han Lopez : I edited it with the advise of user281392.

Comment: @Baloown Thank you, but I am still confused with the answer, so p is the zero polynomial means p=0? But in the question it says p is polynomial with complex coefficient

Comment: Yes : note that $0=0\times 1+0\times X+0\times X^2+...$ can be seen as a polynomial with complex coefficients.

Comment: @Baloown but 0 isn't a complex number right? How can it be a complex coefficient then

Comment: $0$ is : it is $0\times1+0\times i$.

Comment: @Baloown oh yeah 0 is complex number, but I still don't see why the number of roots here matters, how is it related to the P(n)=0 for all integer n

Comment: "$P(n)=0$" says exactly that $n$ is a root of $P$. By the property I have given you in the answer (which is the more important to understand here), you can conclude.